# Condensing Code From a Bingo Game Method

Tags: java

I created a method that populars a 5 x 5 array with integers from 1 - 75 setting the basis for a Bingo Game Card.

```
public static void bingoCard(){

        int [][]card=new int [5][5];
        ArrayList<Integer> alreadyUsed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        boolean valid = false;
        int tmp = 0;

        for(int row=0; row < card.length; row++){
            while(!valid){
                tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+1;
                if(!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)){
                    valid = true;
                    alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
                }
            }
            card[row][0]= tmp;
            valid = false;
        }

        for(int row=0;row<card.length;row++){
            while(!valid){
                tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+16;
                if(!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)){
                    valid = true;
                    alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
                }
            }
            card[row][1]= tmp;
            valid = false;
        }

        for(int row=0;row<card.length;row++){
            while(!valid){
                tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+31;
                if(!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)){
                    valid = true;
                    alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
                }
            }
            card[row][2]= tmp;
            valid = false;
        }

        card[2][2]=0;

        for(int row=0;row<card.length;row++){
            while(!valid){
                tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+46;
                if(!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)){
                    valid = true;
                    alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
                }
            }
            card[row][3]= tmp;
            valid = false;
        }

        for(int row=0;row<card.length;row++){
            while(!valid){
                tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+61;
                if(!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)){
                    valid = true;
                    alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
                }
            }
            card[row][4]= tmp;
            valid = false;
        }

        //create array to make title.  
        String title []={"B","I","N","G","O"};

        for(int i=0;i<title.length;i++){
            System.out.print(title[i]+ "\t");
        }

        System.out.println();

        for(int row=0;row<card.length;row++){
            for(int col=0;col<card[row].length;col++){
                System.out.print(card[row][col]+ "\t");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
```

Sample Output:

```
B   I   N   G   O   
14  23  31  49  66  
13  29  45  52  65  
15  20  0   60  64  
5   21  33  54  63  
6   16  40  57  71
```

I am interested in condensing the code, because as of now, it repeats five rows. Could I get some suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: You should definitely look into nested loops. They are a key building block of all programming.

Comment: @thatidiotguy he's kind of already using nested loops lol

Comment: Well true, but he should use more

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks for the reply. I have a number of nested loops within my loop, which is why I brought up the question. I am unsure as to implement more for-loops in order not to break my code.

Comment: You should consider posting such a question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you want to condense code you should look for patterns. So, let's take a portion of your code:

```
for(int row=0; row < card.length; row++){
    while(!valid){
        tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+1;
        if(!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)){
            valid = true;
            alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
        }
    }
    card[row][0]= tmp;
    valid = false;
}
```

It turns out that most of this repeats throughout your code. The only things that change are:

```
tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+1;
```

and

```
card[row][0]= tmp;
```

So let's look how those two lines change.

```
tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+16;
tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+31;
tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+46;
tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+61;
```

It's easy to see how this changes - it just increases by 15 every time. As for the other line, it just increments by one every time.

Once you've realized this it's easy to write a for loop with blank areas where you need to substitute.

```
for (int i = 0; i < _____; i++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < card.length; row++) {
        while (!valid) {
            tmp = (int) (Math.random() * 15) + _____;
            if (!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)) {
                valid = true;
                alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
            }
        }
        card[row][_____] = tmp;
        valid = false;
     }
}
```

From here, you can fill in the blanks.

Comment: For the first blank, I am assuming `card[col].length`, the second blank is + `(15) + 1`, and `card[row][col+1]`. Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you for the careful explanation, by the way. That really helped.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Well, you don't have a variable called `col`. But yes, the outer loop should go from 0 .. 4. As for the second blank, if you think at every iteration it will amount to `16`. That's right the first time - but you don't want 16, 16, 16, 16, ... you want 16, 31, 46, ... So you have to modify that. And again, for the third blank, you don't have a variable named col. (But you do have a variable called `i`.)

Comment: Ah I see.
First blank: `4`.
Third blank: `i`.

However, for the second blank, I am still unsure.

Comment: First blank: `i <= 4` Second blank: `+ 1 + 15 * i` Third blank: `i` Thank you so much! This worked

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the value of tmp in a parametric fashon and change accordingly with the row number:

```
    int aux = 0;
    for(int row=0;row<card.length;row++){
        while(!valid){
            tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15) + 1 + 15 * aux;
            if(!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)){
                valid = true;
                alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
            }
        }
        card[row][4]= tmp;
        valid = false;
        aux++;
    }
```

Now you can write this only once.

Comment: Why not set aux to 1, add 15 to aux (aux += 15), and drop the multiplication?

Comment: That's much better indeed!

Answer (score 0):

I would nest one of your `for` loops in a second, outer `for` loop that loops over the 5 columns.  The value that you add in each for loop now (1, 16, etc.) can be calculated with this column index, and the column index can be used directly in the the `card` 2D array.

```
for (int col = 0; /* Decide on your bounds here*/ ; col++) {
   // One of your for loops is copied and modified here
   for(int row=0;row<card.length;row++){
        while(!valid){
            tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15) + (/* calculation here*/) + 1;  
            if(!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)){
                valid = true;
                alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
            }
        }
        card[row][/* Decide what to use here*/]= tmp;
        valid = false;
    }
}
```

The logic that controls `[2][2]` can be controlled with an `if`.  I'll leave that as an exercise as to how to include that logic.

Comment: Hi rgettman. Could you show me an example of how I should do this? I have a number of nested loops with-in each loop as well, so I am a little confused if I go any further.

Comment: I've modified my answer to include a template to guide you towards the solution.

Comment: First blank: `i < 4`
Second blank: `+ 1 + 15 * i`
Third blank: `i`

Thank you so much! This worked.